# How to merge array index if the value is same of another index?

Tags: php, arrays

I just pasted my sample input & output.

**Sample Input:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [msisdn] => 10
            [sc] => 8155
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [msisdn] => 20
            [sc] => 22020
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [msisdn] => 10
            [sc] => 8155
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [msisdn] => 10
            [sc] => 8155
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [msisdn] => 20
            [sc] => 22020
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [msisdn] => 30
            [sc] => 22020
        )

)
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1,3,4
            [msisdn] => 10
            [sc] => 8155
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2,5
            [msisdn] => 20
            [sc] => 22020
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [msisdn] => 30
            [sc] => 8155
        )

)
```

Comment: @CodingAnt sometimes people just have no idea on what to do. Give him a break.

Comment: @reformed Mate I just wanted to know at what level he is stucked . Anyways thanks for the enlightment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make that particular value that key, then just concatenate when already pushed/exists:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if(!isset($new_array[$value['msisdn']])) {
        // if not yet pushed, just initialize
        $new_array[$value['msisdn']] = $value;
    } else {
        // if already inside, then just concatenate
        $new_array[$value['msisdn']]['id'] .= ', ' . $value['id'];
    }
}

$new_array = array_values($new_array);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hI87PW)

Comment: you should use `array_key_exists` instead of `isset` in this case

Comment: if [msisdn] value is string instead of numeric value, then what will be the condition? @Ghost

Comment: @Rezuan condition? sorry i don't follow, this will group those values that share the same `msidsn`. as long as they have the same key, the ids will be concatenated.

Comment: Let, there is 5 id's has the same msisdn value. Can I dynamically define the number of id value to split the that array with 2 or 3  id value? For more details please check this link to get the idea of sample input and output [http://txt.do/o2i0] 
sorry for my poor English. @Ghost

Comment: @Rezuan yes you could do that also, you could chunk them by three's so that they will be split by 3, then 2. but of course you'll put them in another process to do that. could you explain the big picture here? i think there something more to it that you haven't explained. anyways, the link you gave is not accessible

Comment: @Ghost sorry for the broken link, Could you please check this link again? https://www.copy.com/s/fVcuYr96Z4xBKrwr/test.txt

Comment: @Rezuan i have seen the textfile. i have a question though, do you have some context to this sort of grouping? how did it came to that expected result? why did `1, 3` be separated with `4, 7` since they share the same `sc` and `msisdn`.

Comment: @Ghost I don't have any context, my office Boss is wanted it from me. Brother is it possible, please give me the solution or what would be the possible solution? :(

Comment: @Ghost there is a limitation that would be 3 or 5 or something like that, if that is cross the limit, it would be another array inside that array. Please Bro help me. See the update file please https://copy.com/yVp7DstNbDSlT9zd
Eagerly waiting for your response. Thanks once again :)

Comment: @Rezuan yeah i'l draft something get to you later in a little bit

Comment: @Ghost thanks its really awesome :) Can i make it dynamic value in the place of 2 -like 3 or 4 and so on, in `array_chunk($value, 2);` ? I just want to make it a variable like $a=2; and put it in that place `array_chunk($value, $a);`

Comment: @Rezuan oh okay, wait a little bit i have to revise something

Comment: @Rezuan here is the demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/cRyCVQ you could just adjust `$num_group` to how many items needs to be grouped

Comment: @Ghost you are really great man :) may god bless you and also thanks for the understood of my poor English and spend your valuable time for me. :) you saved my life. :)

Comment: @Rezuan no prob man, glad this turned out well in the end. well i'm not a native english speaker myself. i only speak broken english lol :D

Answer (score 0):

Live on codepad: http://codepad.org/0fw9k2w9

You can use the fact that in PHP array is an hash map. By creating an intermediate array you can solve this in O(n) time.

```
$merged = array();

foreach($array as $v) {
    $merged[$v['msisdn']][$v['sc']] [] = $v['id'];
}


$final = array();
foreach($merged as $msisdn=>$v) {
   foreach($v as $sc=>$ids) {
       $final [] = array('msisdn'=>$msisdn,'sc'=>$sc,'id'=>$ids);
   }
}
```